# Reasons why reviews might not appear for certain users on Play Store

Tags: google-play

For some users in the US, my play store reviews are not visible. I've reached out to Google directly and am out of options for support, so I've come here.

Here's the official response from Google:

> Please note, since it's based on Google play algorithms, we are not
> able to modify in the rating&review section's result manually. Also
> please understand that, since we don't have any information about
> algorithms, we are not able to further investigate and provide any
> information about your question at this time. I apologize for any
> inconvenience this may cause.
>
> If you have any other Console related question, please let us know.
> We'll be happy to help.
>
> Thanks for supporting Goolge Play.

Very sadly they've given me a generic response about some "algorithm" and are refusing to look into the issue further.

Again, I know this isn't a "standard" question, but I'm not sure where else to go at this point. I feel like I'm at the end of my wits. Any help is appreciated!

What are some reasons why certain users in the US wouldn't be able to see any app reviews, but other users in the US can view these reviews? And is there any reasonable way to "debug" this issue?

Edit: at least one user reports that they are using a Samsung Galaxy phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it takes time for new reviews to show up on google. They also have an algo to check for reviews that might be from "fake users" similar to reddit it may take a while for it to show up entirely and pass their checks.

You have no control on what they show on their App Store reviews section.

One idea to debug is by checking via different android phones using different networks. You can also check the web version App Store link to see if it shows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll wait a bit before accepting.

I was hoping for something more concrete. In my case, these reviews have been about for several months by multiple real users. And still some users still see 0 reviews. I still have trouble believing Google's algorithm would hide these reviews

Comment: Let me know the app link. Also when were the reviews posted?

Comment: Here you go:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.westcote.lovecast
(https://www.lovecastapp.com/)

I think the app store shows the dates of the reviews. But over the last 3-ish months.

Comment: I see 7 reviews. Located in the US. It can also depend on android versions they have. But Now I'm sure they aren't purposely blocking your reviews from showing.

Comment: Thanks for looking! Yes, there should be 7. Appreciate you taking a look!

Yes, I'm not sure what the issue is for certain users. Hmmm. If I don't get another answer, I'll accept yours come tomorrow. Thanks again for taking a look Mohammad